# Index and Match function

Tags: excel

I am having issues making the function Index and Match work together.

Here's my data:

```
A             B            C           D            E
ShortName     Fullname                NumberID     Shortname     
Craig         Craig David             54           John
John          John Long               53           Enrique
Raymond       Raymond Short           23           Craig
Bill          Bill Bush               21           Raymond
```

Here, the column "C" is blank. Basically, I merged two data sheets together (column A and B with column D and E). What I would like is to have the NumberID in column C associated with the shortname in A. Here the NumberID in column D is associated with the shortname in column E.

So far I have tried Vlookup but it is not working. I have tried also Index and Match function but it ain't working either.

What I have:

```
INDEX(D:E;MATCH(A2;E;0);1)
```

I am using Excel in french that's why I used ";" in formula). Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, Column Reference is `E:E` not `E` and you do not need to reference both columns in the INDEX, just the output.

```
=INDEX(D:D;MATCH(A2;E:E;0))
```

[image]