# Excel formula - extract IDs for a specific year - and no previous years

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, formula

I have a sheet with +100 000 records
It is just a product ID and a Year

I need to extract the IDs that have the year 2019 only - and no earlier year than that. So in the image below I just want to get line 9 and 10.
For example, Product ID 4488, has year 2013,2012,2010 so those I want to exclude.

I have tried some conditional formulas but I dont get the result I want

[image]

Comment: Have you considered index() with match() ?

Comment: Not really, I am new to excel, but I can google and see if I can figure it out

Comment: What Excel version do you use

Comment: Excel Version 2016

Comment: Search on here, many examples, this is but one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49152871/4961700

Comment: Thanks, will try and see if I get this, not easy :D

Comment: You can use a Filter, either the AutoFilter or Advanced Filter depending on what you need to do with the results.

Comment: Ok, will look into that, I just need to know those records that have 2019 - and no earlier years than that

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all entries are unique (same ID with same year not repeated). You could use something like this `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,B2=2019),A2,"")` in `C2` and doubleclick or drag down.

COUNTIF finds how many times ID appears in a list (obviously more than one time would mean that there are multiple years). So rest of formula checks if ID appeared only one time and is year 2019.
Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, unfortunately same ID with same year is repeated a lot in the data :(

Comment: You can use "Remove duplicates" in Data -> Remove duplicates while selected both A and B columns before applying formula. There are better ways to get the result, but that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As **[Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld)** Sir has mentioned above in comments you can use `FILTER()` Function, here is something along the lines which you can try.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=VSTACK(A1:B1,FILTER(A2:B10,COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"<>"&2019)=0))
```

---

Or, As the above formula requires, you need to be in **MS365**, hence here is a formula which works with **Excel 2010+ onwards**

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$10)-1)/
(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10,"<>"&2019)=0),ROW(A1)),0),"")
```

Depending on excel version one may need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---